# Sometimes it takes two taps to fire an event. How do I get around this?

Tags: javascript, polymer, dart-polymer

I know this is "by design", but what is the best practice for dealing with this, in a web app and especially Polymer?

I use `on-tap` and sometimes on iOS etc. it takes a few taps to fire whatever event. This makes for terrible UX and we web app developers are already fighting an uphill battle relative to native apps.

Related:

- https://developers.google.com/mobile/articles/fast_buttons
- https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/docs/polymer/touch.html

Comment: Have you tried using touch-down vs on-tap? Or touch-up if you have button-down animation.

Comment: @CalebB about to try `touch-action: none` everywhere. Might that do the trick? Is `touch-down` HTML or Polymer specific?

Comment: It was mentioned in the Polymer article you linked. That could help.

Comment: Checked the source how tap is implemented: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-gestures/blob/master/src/tap.js - it uses up/down already to determinate the tap - however it also takes the position in question .. so your "tap" area might be too small?!

Comment: @Andy has a good point, are the touch areas rather small? possibly enlarging the margin property may ease the ability to make contact if that is indeed the case.

Comment: See my answer! Any issues/thoughts?

Comment: @Andy, I do have that separate issue that sometimes I tap outside of it. But if I increase margins, my design gets affected no? I'd expect the mobile OS to handle a sort of grace area...

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the help folks! This seems to have resolved it for me:

```
body {
  -ms-touch-action: none;
  touch-action: none
}
```

From https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/input/touch/touchevents/#control-gestures-using-touch-actions:

> The CSS property touch-action allows you to control the default touch
>   behavior of an element. In our examples, we use touch-action: none to
>   prevent the browser from doing anything with a users’ touch, allowing
>   us to intercept all of the touch events.
>
> touch-action allows you to disable gestures implemented by a browser.
>   For example, IE10+ supports a double-tap to zoom gesture. By setting a
>   touch-action of pan-x | pan-y | manipulation you prevent the default
>   double-tap behavior. This allows you to implement a double-tap gesture
>   yourself. In the case of IE10+, it also eliminates the 300ms click
>   delay.